# success function is not working angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am sending http request and when that request is finished I am trying to go to another state but the problem is it does not goes in the success callback I thought my be I'm getting an error so I wrote the error callback  it does not goes in that to. Can anybody tell me what am I doing wrong

```
  $scope.submitUpdatedData= function(user){
    debugger;
    // $http.post('/url',{params: value}).sucess(function(){
    API.updateRecord(user).success(function(res){
      $state.go('app' ,{} , {reload: true });
      console.log("Hello");
    });
  }
```

The API code is given below. Here I invoke the http call

```
.factory('API', function($http) {
  var api = {};
  var baseURL = 'http://localhost:3000';

  api.addRecord = function(record) {
      console.log(record);
    // $http.post(baseURL + '/addData', {name: record.name}.);
      return $http.post(baseURL + '/addData', {rec:record});
  };

  api.deleteRecord = function(id){
    return $http.get(baseURL +'/delete/' + id );
  };

  api.updateRecord  = function(user){
    return $http.post(baseURL + "/update/" ,{rec:user});
  };

  api.getAllRecord = function(){
    return $http.get(baseURL+'/getAll');
  };

  api.getOneRecord = function(id){
    return $http.get(baseURL + '/getOne/' + id)
  };

  return api;
})
```

**UPDATE**

I have replaced the .success part with then but it still not works

**Second Update**

This is my server side code

```
  var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var util = require('util');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var app = express();
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
require('node-monkey').start({host: "127.0.0.1", port:"50500"});

var allowCrossDomain = function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');

  next();
};
app.use( bodyParser.json() );
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({     // to support URL-encoded bodies
  extended: true
}));
// app.use(express.json());       // to support JSON-encoded bodies
// app.use(express.urlencoded()); // to support URL-encoded bodies
app.use(allowCrossDomain);
// app.use('/' , require('./index'))
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/myappdatabase');

var userSchema = new Schema({
  name:  String,
  password: String
});



var Todo = mongoose.model('Todo', userSchema);


app.get('/getAll' , function(req, res){
    Todo.find({} , function(err , todos){
      if (err){
        res.send(err);
      }
      console.log(todos);
      res.send(todos);
    });
});

app.get('/delete/:name' , function(req , res){
  console.log(req.params);
  console.log(req.params.name);
  Todo.remove({
            name : req.params.name
        }, function(err, todo) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);
            // get and return all the todos after you create another
            Todo.find(function(err, todos) {
                if (err)
                    res.send(err)
                res.json(todos);
            });
        });
});

app.get('/getOne/:id' , function(req , res){
  Todo.find({name : req.params.id}, function(err, todo) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);
            res.send  (todo[0]);
            // get and return all the todos after you create another
        });
});


app.post('/update', function(req , res){
  console.log(req.param('rec').name);
  Todo.update({_id:req.param('rec').id} , {$set : {name:req.param('rec').name , password:req.param('rec').password}} , function(err){
    if(err)
      res.send("Error occured");
    res.send("true");
  });
});


app.post('/addData' , function(req , res){
  console.log( req.param('rec').name);

  var p = new Todo({name: req.param('rec').name  , password: req.param('rec').password});
  p.save(function(err){
    if(err){
      res.send(err);
      console.log(error);
    }
    res.json(p);
  });
});


var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;

  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});



// module.exports = app;
```

Comment: did you declare `API` at the top of your controller? and whats the exact error?

Comment: @JoeLloyd yes I declared API and it's not an error it's just that when the result from the updateRecord return it neither goes in the success and error callbacks

Comment: What version of angular? .success was deprecated, i wonder if the latest still includes it.

Comment: @KevinB what is the replacement for `success`? I didn't realise it was depreciated, probably why my app has errors haha. 

@james are you sure your states are correct? Like have you tried just calling `$state.go(someState)` with a button click?

Comment: Yes it does. Using it throws errors though if $httpProvider.useLegacyPromiseExtensions is set to false.

Comment: .then would be the replacement. You should also use .catch to catch any errors.

Comment: @KevinB angular version is v1.4.3

Comment: @JoeLloyd yes I have tried calling this way and they are working correctly

Comment: could it be that the data you're trying to enter is wrong? or the api call itself is off? have you double checked it with postman?

Comment: I also suspect this to be a problem in the server side code. Can you provide your code for this API endpoint?

Comment: @Mad-C I have added the server side code

Comment: Maybe {_id:req.param('rec').id} is the wrong query. You are using name in all other queries. I am not that familiar with mongoose, but it might be possible that there is no update event, thus the callback (and therefore the res.json calls) are never called.

Comment: @Mad-C the data is being updated

Comment: Did you check if the callback of the update method (of the Todo model) is ever called? I second the request of double checking the post request with postman.

Comment: @Mad-C yes the callback of the update is called I consoled the output

Answer (score 3):

Seems like `success` and `error` are deprecated, you should use `then` instead:

```
API.updateRecord(user).then(function(res){
    $state.go('app' ,{} , {reload: true });
    console.log("Hello");
});
```

> The $http legacy promise methods success and error have been
>   deprecated. Use the standard then method instead. If
>   $httpProvider.useLegacyPromiseExtensions is set to false then these
>   methods will throw $http/legacy error.
>   Source [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Comment: yes I did try using then but that does not works either

Comment: and the version is v1.4.3. I have used it in other functions and it's working correctly but here it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your request is never answered by the API Server. Maybe you can set a timeout for your request. [Here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) it says you can do:

```
$http.post(url, data, {timeout: 100});
```

That should timeout your request after 100ms.

Comment: It is answered by the server but it does not enters the callbacks

Comment: How did you test if the server answers if you are not getting any callbacks?

Comment: But that only checks if the db is contacted, that does not mean the server ever sends a response.

Comment: Sorry I did not tell it in the previous comment but a promise is also being returned